# Add custom field to additional image (renamed to Specification) tab, no plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields

I am trying to add a custom field into the product attributes tab. We've renamed it Specification in our case, not sure if that matters.

Here is the code to create the custom fields, and I can successfully manipulate and put them around on the product page, but not in the product_attributes tab.

The product_attributes tab always exists for every product in our site with how it is built.

Code:

```
// Test in Additional Info
// -----------------------------------------
// 1. Add custom field input @ Product Data > Variations > Single Variation

add_action( 'woocommerce_variation_options_pricing', 'bbloomer_add_test_cf_to_variations', 10, 3 ); 

function bbloomer_add_test_cf_to_variations( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ) {
woocommerce_wp_text_input( array( 
'id' => 'test_cf[' . $loop . ']', 
'class' => 'short', 
'label' => __( 'Test', 'woocommerce' ),
'value' => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, 'test_cf', true )
) 
);      
}

// -----------------------------------------
// 2. Save custom field on product variation save

add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'bbloomer_save_test_cf_variations', 10, 2 );

function bbloomer_save_test_cf_variations( $variation_id, $i ) {
    $test_cf = $_POST['test_cf'][$i];
    if ( ! empty( $test_cf ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $variation_id, 'test_cf', esc_attr( $test_cf ) );
    } else delete_post_meta( $variation_id, 'test_cf' );
}

// 3. Store custom delivery value into variation data 

add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'bbloomer_add_test_cf_variation_data' );

function bbloomer_add_test_cf_variation_data( $variations ) {

    $test = get_post_meta( $variations[ 'variation_id' ], 'test_cf', true );
    if( ! empty( $test ) ) {
    $variations['test_cf'] = '<div>Test: <span>' . get_post_meta( $variations[ 'variation_id' ], 'test_cf', true ) . '</span></div>';
    }
    return $variations;
}
```

Usually, when adding custom_fields this way, I would add them to variation.php override file, and then I could manipulate them with the css.

I have tried adding the following to product-attributes.php:

```
<script type="text/template" id="tmpl-variation-template">
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-test">{{{ data.variation.test_cf }}}</div>
</script>
<script type="text/template" id="tmpl-unavailable-variation-template">
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, this product is unavailable. Please choose a different combination.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
</script>
```

But I cannot get them to display at all.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what exactly should be displayed there, it looks like you want share some information about delivery time?

**STEP 1**

create a function in your themes functions.php. I've placed some comments to explain whats going on.

```
 /**
  * Template hook points at product_attributes.php
  *
  * @template product-attributes.php
  */
   add_action('custom_template_hook', 'display_custom_field' , 10 , 1);
    function display_custom_field($product) {
      // Check if product is variable
      if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ){
          // If so, get all available variations!
        $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
            // Loop through variations
          foreach ($variations as $variation) {
              // Check if meta field isn't empty, if not display the field!
            if (!empty(get_post_meta( $variation['variation_id'], 'test_cf', true))) {
                 // get product object from variation ID
                 $product_obj = wc_get_product( $variation['variation_id'] );
              ?>
              <tr class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item">
                <th class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__label"><?php  echo $product_obj->get_name() ?></th>
                <td class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value"><?php echo wp_kses_post( get_post_meta( $variation['variation_id'], 'test_cf', true ) ); ?></td>
              </tr>
              <?
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

**STEP 2**

In product-attributes isn't a hook you can use, so you have to put a line of code in product-attributes.php
Personally i would suggest using a child-theme, otherwise you possibly lose your changes on future updates.

```
do_action('custom_template_hook', $product);
```

Your product-attributes.php file should look like this!

```
<?php
/**
 * Product attributes
 *
 * Used by list_attributes() in the products class.
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product/product-attributes.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 3.6.0
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

if ( ! $product_attributes ) {
    return;
}


?>
<table class="woocommerce-product-attributes shop_attributes">
    <?php foreach ( $product_attributes as $product_attribute_key => $product_attribute ) : ?>
        <tr class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item woocommerce-product-attributes-item--<?php echo esc_attr( $product_attribute_key ); ?>">
            <th class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__label"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $product_attribute['label'] ); ?></th>
            <td class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $product_attribute['value'] ); ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; 
        do_action('custom_template_hook', $product);
    ?>
</table>
```

Hope this helps, if you encounter any issues, let me know!

Comment: Hey! Thanks so much. It does work. However, it is rendering the product title, then the custom field data, instead of the text "Test" - How can I make it use just text, followed by the custom field value?

Comment: Ok never mind, I managed to make the title display. The issue I've now got is that it is displaying ALL variation values in a single tab. I only want it to display the custom field value for the variation when selected.

So for example, if the title of the new custom field attribute was "Delivery Time", and the product was a T-Shirt with 3 colours, I would input "3 Days" into the colour Red, and when clicking the attributes tab for that colour, it would only show 3 days, even if the Green T-Shirt had it's own value of 5 days.

Comment: If you want the value displayed based on the variation the customer has selected, there is no way around using JavaScript. If you need help on this, please let me know.

Comment: What do you mean sorry? It works for all other custom fields, using the original method I posted, just for some reason 

        do_action('custom_template_hook', $product);

is showing all of the variation id custom fields, I'd like it to just show the field for the variation id selected

Comment: Ok, I see now. It needs to use a script. I would desperately need help with that! If we could get it done via chat, that would be great! I'll constatntly refresh till you are around, I'm approaching 24 hours banging my head at a wall :)

Comment: If, in variation.php, I add the following:
```<script type="text/template" id="tmpl-variation-template">
 <div class="woocommerce-variation-price">{{{ data.variation.price_html }}}</div>

 <div class="woocommerce-variation-test">{{{ data.variation.test_cf }}}</div>
</script>```
It does display correctly as per each variation. However, it's just floating around next to the add to the cart button, so I need to get this into the specification tab where the product attributes are, but without breaking the existing custom fields that are in variations.php.

Comment: please give me a while, i'll update the answer including the necessary Javascript! Hopefully the wall isn't made from concrete :)

Comment: Sorry data.variation.price_html should have been data.variation.test_cf in above comment! Ok that would be awesome. Thanks so much for your kind help.